# Deleting data using Id in mongodb is giving me CastError

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I tried to delete an entry in MongoDB using mongoose 'findByIdAndRemove' function, it is giving me '***Cast to ObjectId failed for value error***'.

Delete Service

```
routes.delete('/:id',async(req,res) =>{
Employee.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).then(employee=>{
    if(employee)
    {
        return res.status(200).json({success:true,message:"the employee entry is removed successfully"});
    } else{
        return res.status(404).json({success:false,message:"employee entry is not removed"});
    }
})
})
```

How to validate the id before the 'findByIdAndRemove' delete call to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by importing mongoose into the module and validating the 'Id' before the
delete call using the function `mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)`.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Service call

```
routes.delete('/:id',async(req,res) =>{
if(mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id))
{
Employee.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).then(employee =>{
    if(employee)
    {
        return res.status(200).json({success:true,message:"the employee entry removed successfully"});
    } else{
        return res.status(404).json({success:false,message:"employee entry is not removed"});
    }
})
}
else {
    return res.status(400).send('Invalid Id');
}
})
```